# Changing downloaded template nav color confusion

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to change the color of the navbar. I have worked with HTML and CSS, but havent really made design changes before. And for some reason I cannot figure out for the life of me how to make changes to this html/css template I downloaded.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">CandyCode</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

I am not really sure what to change in the CSS. Essentially I would like to change the navbars color to #77bbb0. I can show more code, but I think for the sake of clarity, you can check out the code here: http://startbootstrap.com/blog-home.

Thank for helping a design noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to give the HTML element in question an id and then add the CSS rule:

```
#the_id_i_gave_it { background:#77bbb0; }
```

However, if you can't or don't want to edit the markup, you can chain together the various classes on the element to give your rule high specificity:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top { background:#77bbb0; }
```

As long as those classes don't change that should be specific enough to get just the div you want and no others.